# Coroutine Called From Update Wont Work, IEnumerator Wont Run. Where Did I Go Wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

So how my code below should work is as such: The player collects 5 collectables, after which, the Coroutine is meant to start - an achievement notification pops up and plays a sound.
But upon testing, it just doesn't work, the "ach01Code" sets to 12345 on start rather than AFTER 5 collectables have been picked up.
I thought maybe I was setting the ach01Code on start by accident but I can't see where I went wrong.

````
  //General Vars
   public GameObject achNotif;
   public AudioSource achSound;
   public bool achActive = false;
   public GameObject achTitle;
   public GameObject achText;
   
   //Collection Based (01)
   public GameObject ach01Image;
   public static int ach01Count;
   public int ach01Trigger = 5;
   public int ach01Code;
   
   private void Update()
   {
      ach01Code = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Ach01");
      if (ach01Count == ach01Trigger && ach01Code != 12345)
      {
         StartCoroutine(Trigger01Ach());
         Debug.Log("Achievement Collected!");
      }
   }

   IEnumerator Trigger01Ach()
   {
      achActive = true;
      ach01Code = 12345;
      PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Ach01", ach01Code);
      achSound.Play();
      ach01Image.SetActive(true);
      achTitle.GetComponent<Text>().text = "COLLECTION!";
      achText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Created A Collection Based Achievement";
      achNotif.SetActive(true);
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);
      //Reset UI
      achNotif.SetActive(false);
      ach01Image.SetActive(false);
      achTitle.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
      achText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
      achActive = false;
   }```
````

Comment: After the coroutine runs once `ach01Code = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Ach01");` will always read `12345`. You never set it to anything else in the code shown.

Comment: I know but my problem is that the coroutine isn't running at all, ah01Code reads 12345 as soon as I press play.

Comment: If you manually put  `StartCoroutine(Trigger01Ach());` inside Start(), does it execute?

Comment: where is `ach01Code` set? what is it's serialised value? why is it `public`?

Comment: It's saved in your preferences because the coroutine ran once. `ach01Code = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Ach01");` retrieves it every time. Unless you overwrite it with something else or delete that key it is forever.